# Can't pair phonegap desktop app with phonegap developer app on my windows phone

Tags: phonegap-desktop-app

i just downloaded the phonegap desktop app 0.1.1 beta and installed it on my computer (windows O.S 64-bit) and then downloaded the developer app on my windows phone( Nokia Lumia 620)... I ran the phonegap desktop app and was able to create a new project. However i have not been able to pair the desktop app to developer app on my phone.I just keep getting " Download error! " even after entering the server address of the desktop app into the developer app on my phone. Any ideas on how to solve this ? I am new to coding mobile applications and have to code a mobile tracking app for my project.

Comment: Try to add more details like, steps you took, tutorials you fallow, the phone you are using, etc. It will make easier for other to help you! Good luck!

Comment: Meiyappan's suggestions are a good start, but if you are still having issues, try some of the few below. 1. First, please try following the steps in Phonegap's troubleshooting documentation.
- http://docs.phonegap.com/references/developer-app/troubleshoot-faq/ 2. After completing those steps and if you're still having problems, can you check to see if you enabled making your PC discoverable to other devices?
- http://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-set-your-networks-location-private-or-public-windows-10.
- This was a simple error that I had overlooked and was the root issue in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the last release (0.1.9) and now it works on my android device.
Version 0.1.8 was not working. Maybe you already found it out.

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-app-desktop/releases

Answer (score 0):

Could you please add more details on this. I had same issue . I did below

1. Open the Desktop server url in Chrome or Mozilla and check whether it works. If it works there is an issue with Desktop app connected to different network than your developer app in phone.
2. Stop and start the server again in desktop and check whether the URL has been changed. Now add this URL in phonegap developer app in mobile device. It should work.